# android - multiple touch actions

Tags: android, visibility, swipe, ontouchlistener

i am trying to load images from url and show one by one by swiping them. My swiping codes are working good. Now i need to place a header and footer for the page.

The header and footer needs to get invisible withing 10 sec and once the user taps on the screen, it must get re-appeared and in next 10 sec it must be invisible. I created a handler class for making visible and invisible. Both the codes are seems to work in separate but when i join all together, the swipe is not working in touch.

in my layout i need the footer and header to be over the image view, so my xml file is as follows

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageView>    </ImageView>
    <RelativeLayout>
       <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
       </RelativeLayout>
       <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
       </RelativeLayout> 
   </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

My onTouch action is to be as follows

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            System.out.println("Touch Down X:" + event.getX() + " Y:" + event.getY());
            hide_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            System.out.println("Touch Up X:" + event.getX() + " Y:" + event.getY());
            startProgress();
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        else if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

startProgress() is the handler class, which makes the relative layout to be invisible again

```
public void startProgress()
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                handler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        hide_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some additional information to make it possible to find whats going wrong:

- What is doing `startProgress()` method
- Do you have motion event (or click) handling in the header and/or footer

As a general point for attention, keep in mind that Android is delivering motion events to view hierarchy, starting from the last added and moving sequetialy until one consumes it (returning true) or until getting to the first view added.

So on your layout, as footer is the last added view, it will be the first recieving the motion event, followed by header and only after it will delivered to the imageView, if not consumed before.

Comment: You didn't answer 2nd point I asked above. Try using `hide_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in your `startProgress()`. This will remove the header and footer from the views receiving motion evnts.

Comment: i have the motion event for header and footer. Visibility gone is also not working. Once the layouts gets gone, when again the user touches i want to make it visible, in swipe i need to load next image. Only touch action is taking place....